# Clear Microsoft Office Add-Ins cache

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-office, add-in, powerpoint

I wrote some code in an add-in for Microsoft PowerPoint 2007. I executed it. It said there was a problem.

With [help from a fellow member here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855513/callbackoncollecteddelegate-was-detected), I rectified the problem. I compiled the new code and ran it.

It still considers the old code and ignores the new one and still throws the same problem. The two versions of code are radically different in that they do not share the variables that the problem reports, thus my reason for being sure that the problem isn't in the code now.

Clearly, MS Office is retaining an older version of the binaries somewhere in some cache. How do I clear that and allow it to access the newly compiled add-in binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your problem is indeed with cached assemblies, they would most likely be located here:

```
%userprofile%\local Settings\Application Data\assembly
```

Preserve the folder structure in that folder (another words, **dl3**, **temp**, **tmp**), but clear out any files and folders under those 3 folders.

Remember to close all instances of PowerPoint via TaskManager/Processes tab before you do this. Closing the application alone is not good enough - you must hunt down every instance of the PowerPoint process that are running.

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved me hours. Just so I do not forget, I am writing this for my own sake, and for the sake of anyone else having the same problem. Another thing to do before deleting those files (or they'll keep coming back magically) from the dl3 folder is to open Power Point or whatever other MS Office app you want the cache cleared off of, and go to the add-ins dialog box and de-select and/or remove those add-ins. Thanks again, code4life, I saw all the assemblies and their debug symbols in this folder.