# CallbackOnCollectedDelegate in globalKeyboardHook was detected

Tags: c#

I'm using a global keyboard hook class. This class allows to check if keyboard key pressed anywhere. And after some time I'm having an error:

```
        **CallbackOnCollectedDelegate was detected**

A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type 'Browser!Utilities.globalKeyboardHook+keyboardHookProc::Invoke'. This may cause application crashes, corruption and data loss. When passing delegates to unmanaged code, they must be kept alive by the managed application until it is guaranteed that they will never be called.
```

Here is globalkeyboardHook class:

```
        public delegate int keyboardHookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam);

        public struct keyboardHookStruct
        {
            public int vkCode;
            public int scanCode;
            public int flags;
            public int time;
            public int dwExtraInfo;
        }

        const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
        const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
        const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;
        const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x105;

        public List<Keys> HookedKeys = new List<Keys>();

        IntPtr hhook = IntPtr.Zero;

        public event KeyEventHandler KeyDown;
        public event KeyEventHandler KeyUp;

        public globalKeyboardHook()
        {
            hook();
        }

        ~globalKeyboardHook()
        {
            unhook();
        }

        public void hook()
        {
            IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
            hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hookProc, hInstance, 0);
        }

        public void unhook()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
        }

        public int hookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam)
        {
            if (code >= 0)
            {
                Keys key = (Keys)lParam.vkCode;
                if (HookedKeys.Contains(key))
                {
                    KeyEventArgs kea = new KeyEventArgs(key);
                    if ((wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) && (KeyDown != null))
                    {
                        KeyDown(this, kea);
                    }
                    else if ((wParam == WM_KEYUP || wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP) && (KeyUp != null))
                    {
                        KeyUp(this, kea);
                    }
                    if (kea.Handled)
                        return 1;
                }
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, wParam, ref lParam);
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, keyboardHookProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);


        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
        #endregion
```

Any ideas how to fix it? The program works well, but after some time the program freezes ant I get this error.

Comment: Try holding a reference to the delegate in your class to hookProc - an actual member. I am not sure if that will solve everything, but it should solve your collection issue as long as your hook class is still alive.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hookProc, hInstance, 0);
```

There's your problem.  You are relying on C# syntax sugar to have it automatically create a delegate object to *hookProc*.  Actual code generation look like this:

```
keyboardHookProc $temp = new keyboardHookProc(hookProc);
hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, $temp, hInstance, 0);
```

There's only one reference to the delegate object, $temp.  But it is local variable and disappears as soon as your hook() method stops executing and returns.  The garbage collector is otherwise powerless to see that Windows has a 'reference' to it as well, it cannot probe unmanaged code for references.  So the next time the garbage collector runs, the delegate object gets destroyed.  And that's a kaboom when Windows makes the hook callback.  The built-in MDA detects the problem and generates the helpful diagnostic before the program crashes with an AccessViolation.

You will need to create an additional reference to the delegate object that survives long enough.  You could use GCHandle for example.  Or easier, just store a reference yourself so the garbage collector can always see the reference.  Add a field to your class.  Making it static is a sure-fire way to ensure the object can't be collected:

```
    private static keyboardHookProc callbackDelegate;

    public void hook()
    {
        if (callbackDelegate != null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't hook more than once");
        IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
        callbackDelegate = new keyboardHookProc(hookProc);
        hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, callbackDelegate, hInstance, 0);
        if (hhook == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Win32Exception();
    }

    public void unhook()
    {
        if (callbackDelegate == null) return;
        bool ok = UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
        if (!ok) throw new Win32Exception();
        callbackDelegate = null;
    }
```

No need to pinvoke FreeLibrary, user32.dll is always loaded until your program terminates.

Comment: if the User32 is always loaded, why do I explicitly load it in method hook()?

Comment: I don't have a time machine to know if is still true 20 years from now.

Comment: Good answer, but I'd recommend to not make `callbackDelegate` static. If you do, your callbacks will be garbage collected again if you have multiple instances of your class. (Or in your example you can only hook once with multiple instances which makes the instantiation of the class useless)

Comment: That's nonsensical, installing the hook more than once is a gross bug.  It *must* be static, Windows will keep calling the callback until the hook is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't take too long to get it done! 
Here's an all good working implementation with latest fix (definitions & implementations) following **Hans Passant's** answer and a GitHub project.

```
//file Win32Api.cs
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using YourProjectNamespace.Hooks;

    namespace YourProjectNamespace
    {

        public delegate int keyboardHookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam);
        /// <summary>
        ///     Pcursor info
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct PCURSORINFO
        {
            public Int32 Size;
            public Int32 Flags;
            public IntPtr Cursor;
            public POINTAPI ScreenPos;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Point
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct POINTAPI
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     keyboard hook struct
        /// </summary>
        public struct keyboardHookStruct
        {
            public int dwExtraInfo;
            public int flags;
            public int scanCode;
            public int time;
            public int vkCode;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Wrapper for windows 32 calls.
        /// </summary>
        public class Win32Api
        {
            public const Int32 CURSOR_SHOWING = 0x00000001;
            public const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
            public const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
            public const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
            public const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;
            public const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x105;

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern bool GetCursorInfo(out PCURSORINFO cinfo);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern bool DrawIcon(IntPtr hDC, int X, int Y, IntPtr hIcon);

            [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
            private static extern int mciSendString(string MciComando, string MciRetorno, int MciRetornoLeng, int CallBack);

            [DllImport("user32")]
            private static extern int GetKeyboardState(byte[] pbKeyState);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
            private static extern short GetKeyState(int vKey);

            [DllImport("user32")]
            public static extern int ToAscii(
                int uVirtKey,
                int uScanCode,
                byte[] lpbKeyState,
                byte[] lpwTransKey,
                int fuState);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
                CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
            public static extern int CallNextHookEx(
                IntPtr idHook,
                int nCode,
                int wParam,
                ref keyboardHookStruct lParam);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
                CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern int UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr idHook);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
                CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(
                int idHook,
                keyboardHookProc lpfn,
                IntPtr hMod,
                int dwThreadId);




            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);


            //Constants
        } // class Win32




 **File GlobalKeyboardHook.cs**


    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using log4net;

    namespace ScreenRecorder.Hooks
    {

        public class GlobalKeyboardHook
        {
            private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (GlobalKeyboardHook).Name);

            const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
            const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
            const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
            const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;
            const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x105;

            private static keyboardHookProc callbackDelegate;


            public List<Keys> HookedKeys = new List<Keys>();
            private IntPtr keyboardHook = IntPtr.Zero;




            /// <summary>
            public GlobalKeyboardHook()
            {
                Hook();
            }

            ~GlobalKeyboardHook() {
                Unhook();
            }

            public event KeyEventHandler KeyDown;
            public event KeyEventHandler KeyUp;


            public int HookProc(int nCode, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam)
            {
                if (nCode >= 0)
                {
                    var key = (Keys) lParam.vkCode;
                    if (HookedKeys.Contains(key))
                    {
                        var kArgs = new KeyEventArgs(key);
                        if ((wParam == Win32Api.WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == Win32Api.WM_SYSKEYDOWN) && (KeyDown != null))
                        {
                            KeyDown(this, kArgs);
                        }
                        else if ((wParam == Win32Api.WM_KEYUP || wParam == Win32Api.WM_SYSKEYUP) && (KeyUp != null))
                        {
                            KeyUp(this, kArgs);
                        }
                        if (kArgs.Handled)
                            return 1;
                    }
                }
                return Win32Api.CallNextHookEx(keyboardHook, nCode, wParam, ref lParam);
            }



            public void Hook()
            {
                // Create an instance of HookProc.


                //if (callbackDelegate != null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Multiple hooks are not allowed!");
                IntPtr hInstance = Win32Api.LoadLibrary("User32");
                callbackDelegate = new keyboardHookProc(HookProc);

                //install hook
                keyboardHook = Win32Api.SetWindowsHookEx( Win32Api.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, callbackDelegate, hInstance, 0);

                //If SetWindowsHookEx fails.
                if (keyboardHook == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    //Returns the error code returned by the last unmanaged function called using platform invoke that has the DllImportAttribute.SetLastError flag set. 
                    var errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

                    log.Error("Unable to install keyboard hook.", new Win32Exception(errorCode));
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            ///     Unsubscribe for keyboard hook
            /// </summary>
            public void Unhook()
            {
                if (callbackDelegate == null) return;



                if (keyboardHook != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    //uninstall hook
                    var retKeyboard = Win32Api.UnhookWindowsHookEx(keyboardHook);
                    //reset invalid handle
                    keyboardHook = IntPtr.Zero;
                    //if failed and exception must be thrown
                    if (retKeyboard == 0)
                    {
                        //Returns the error code returned by the last unmanaged function called using platform invoke that has the DllImportAttribute.SetLastError flag set. 
                        var errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                        //Initializes and throws a new instance of the Win32Exception class with the specified error. 
                        log.Error("Error while uninstalling keyboard hook", new Win32Exception(errorCode));
                    }
                }

                callbackDelegate = null;
            }
        }


    }
```