# How can I implement persistent callbacks from C++ to C#?

Tags: c#, c++

I need to pass a series of callbacks, which will be called from native code in C++ into C#/WPF application. This is how I'm doing it right now:

#### C++ callback definition

```cpp
namespace omk_api
{
    enum LogSeverity : int
    {
        Error = 1,
        Warning = 2,
        Info = 3,
        Trace = 4
    };

    typedef void(__stdcall* logProc)(const wchar_t* source, const wchar_t* message, LogSeverity severity);
}
```

#### C++ function export

```cpp
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void* __stdcall CreateController(omk_api::logProc log)
{
    return (void*)(new omk_controller::Controller(log));
}
```

#### Relevant C# code

```cs
    public class Controller : IDisposable
    {
        private IntPtr instance;
        private LogProc logProc;

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private delegate void LogProc([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string source, 
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string message, 
            LogSeverity severity);

        // (...)

        [DllImport("OpenMacroKeyboard.Controller.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr CreateController(LogProc log);

        // (...)

        private void Log(string source, string message, LogSeverity severity)
        {

        }

        // Public methods -----------------------------------------------------

        public Controller()
        {
            logProc = new LogProc(Log);
            instance = CreateController(logProc);
        }

        // (...)
    }
```

My question is: do I need to perform any additional operations to be sure that the pointer passed to C++ will remain unchanged (so that there won't be weird crashes caused by the garbage collector moving things around)? C++ objects' lifetime will be equal to their C# wrappers, so I'm not worried about the actual garbage collection.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5526777/4641116

Comment: @Eljay It is [not required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45787664/11683) to pin delegeates for them to remain functional. The delegate objects themelves can be moved around, their internal pointer will stay the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need to pin an anonymous delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465060/do-i-need-to-pin-an-anonymous-delegate)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass function pointer from C# to a C++ Dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43226928/11683)

Comment: You have to make sure that the delegate object can't get garbage collected, the GG cannot see that the unmanaged code uses it to make callbacks.  Right now it is tied to the lifetime of Controller, without any obvious cleanup that makes it clear it stays alive long enough.  Make its reference static, for example.

Comment: Create another callback `DeleteController` and ask C++ to free it while your C# wrapper get removed by gc. Aka: call `DeleteController` in your C# object destructor (or `Dispose()`? haven't use C# for a while)